# CSS margin connected?

Tags: html, css, margin

Below print screen from google chrome html/css view.

[image: Upper margin]

[image: Lower margin]

One element under another, `margin: 10px;`, so they should be 20px from each other.

But they aren't. They are 10px apart, like the margins are connected.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("2.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    font-size: 17px;
}
#logo {
  background-image: url("logo.png");
  width: 527px;
  height: 58px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #55585d;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #44474c;
  border-top: 2px solid #44474c;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.nav > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
/* 1195px width */
#center {
  width: 1195px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#container {
  width: 864px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  float: left;
}
.post {
  width: 392px;
  height: 453px;
  box-shadow: 3px -3px 6px 0px #000000,
  -1px 1px 1px 0px #000000;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
#aside {
  width: 315px;
  float: left;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.abox1 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 279px;
  height: 453px;
  box-shadow: 3px -3px 6px 0px #000000,
  -1px 1px 1px 0px #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Devloger</title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <h1 class="hidden">Devloger</h1>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          Strona Główna
        </li>
        <li>
          Kategorie
        </li>
        <li>
          Spis Treści
        </li>
        <li>
          Współpraca
        </li>
        <li>
          Kontakt
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="center">
  <main>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="post">
      </div>
      <div class="post">
      </div>
      <div class="post">
      </div>
      <div class="post">
      </div>
      <div class="post">
      </div>
      <div class="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <div id="aside">
      <div class="abox1">
      </div>
      <div class="abox1">
      </div>
      <div class="abox1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: take it easy man !

Comment: This is [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

Comment: Why does mine collapsed? : /

Answer (score 0):

There are cases ([you can read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)) where margins between elements are collapsed (overlapped, one on top of the other), and this is an intended behaviour, so it's not an error.

This is one of these cases and your current issue:

> **Adjacent siblings**
>
> *The margins of adjacent siblings are collapsed (except when the later sibling needs to be cleared past floats).*

First you have some `.post` blocks with that margins, but these margins are working well because that blocks are floated. If you remove `float: left` from `.post` class you will see that these blocks margins are collapsed as well.

---

Knowing that margin collapsing exists, you can take it into account when designing layouts:

Page flow goes from left to right, **top to bottom**. So instead of define a `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, define only a `margin-bottom`.

```css
aside {
  width: 315px;
  float: left;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.abox1 {
  margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;
  width: 279px;
  height: 453px;
  box-shadow: 3px -3px 6px 0px #000000,
  -1px 1px 1px 0px #000000;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="abox1"></div>
  <div class="abox1"></div>
  <div class="abox1"></div>
</aside>
```